# Could not process parameters in a query with python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do a simple query in Python with mysql and I have this error and I don't know why I have this error:

```
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

What I am doing is this:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql="SELECT pathFile FROM googlesearch where tweetid=%d LIMIT 1"
print(lastid)
print(sql)
mycursor.execute(sql,(lastid),)
mydb.commit()
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
```

Why I have this error?. It is a simple query as you can see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a comma in the line:
`mycursor.execute(sql,(lastid),)`

`(lastid,)` is a tuple, but `(lastid)` is not.

So use `mycursor.execute(sql,(lastid,),)` instead (note the comma after `lastid`)

for futher reference [check the docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html):

It says:

> **Note:**
>   In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For example, ('abc') is evaluated as a scalar while ('abc',) is evaluated as a tuple.